# sql: 'Union all' cannot union Chinese characters field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to union 2 tables, however, 1 field has Chinese characters, and it is not successful to union. However, only select statement is okay to show Chinese Character.

```
select id, ChineseName, Location, Scores
from ((select select id, ChineseName, Location, Scores from Table1)
union all
(select id, ChineseName, Location, Scores from Table2))t
```

Running above sql returns error msg:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '香港' to data type int.

After removing the field `ChineseName`, the sql is okay to union.

How can I solve this Chinese field problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please show us the types for all columns from both tables.

Comment: sorry, I use #tempdb for saving the table, I don't know how to show those types by clicking sql server panel

Comment: The error says that you tried to mix up characer and text fields ` Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '香港' to data type int.` It has nothing to do with Chinese support.

Comment: You use two `select` on your subquery..

Comment: @YungLinMa the query you posted contains syntax errors. Post the *actual* query. Most likely you repeated a field somewhere or switched the location of some fileds, eg `ID` and `ChineseName`

Comment: @YungLinMa how did you *create* the temporary tables in the first place? What query did you use? People can't help unless they can reproduce the issue.

Comment: running the above union sql has no intention to convert anything to integer. I feel confused about the error msg

Comment: @YungLinMa in any case SQL Server works with Chinese just fine and your own question proves it. SO is an ASP.NET site and questions are  stored in SQL Server tables as nvarchar fields. You wouldn't be able to post your query if there were Unicode issues

Comment: @YungLinMa it means that you are trying to return both an int and an nvarchar field in the same location. Either you aren't posting the entire query or one of the temporary tables has the wrong type. How did you create them? You may have mixed up the field types

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos Sorry, those are company information, I am unable to post it online. select statement is okay for those 2 tables, however, this error occurred on union statement

Comment: @YungLinMa of course you can. Use a `CREATE TABLE` query with the fields in question in a new database. I can create an example that shows I can make a UNION with the data you provided quite easily.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, I didn't use create table, i use select .. into #Table1. Thus, I have no idea how to check that data type. However, I suppose no need to check it, just simply convert it or cast it? any thoughts

Comment: @YungLinMa create a normal table the same way and check its structure, ie `SELECT ... INTO temp_Table1`. I'll bet there's a typo in one of those SELECT INTO queries that stores the text into the ID or some other numeric field

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos I checked thoroughly and no typo at all, because removing 'ChineseName' field work perfectly. that is meant there is not typo, like below:
select id,  Location, Scores
from ((select select id,  Location, Scores from Table1)
union all
(select id,  Location, Scores from Table2))t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well let's start of how the table definitions should be

```
create table table1(
  id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
  ChineseName nvarchar(max), 
  Location nvarchar(max), 
  Scores int
)

create table table2(
  id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
  ChineseName nvarchar(max), 
  Location nvarchar(max), 
  Scores int
)
```

and now applying your query to fetch the data (small changes only):

```
 select id, ChineseName, Location, Scores
from (
select id, ChineseName, Location, Scores from table1
union all
select id, ChineseName, Location, Scores from table2
 ) t
```

and it worked, i also have created the test environment, check and find out what mistake you must be making by comparing with your 'table definition and their types and the data': [Test Environment](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5834a/5)

Comment: Hi ARr0w, what if I create those 2 tables by into # table1 and into # table2?

Comment: @YungLinMa just add `#` in front of the name. It *doesn't* matter though, fiedl type behaviour doesn't change just because they are temporary.

Comment: @ARr0w your test environment is showing '??' in Chinese character, I am not sure is it normal or not.(my browser support Chinese) however, is there any way to change the field type to union those 2 with Chinese characters tables successfully?

Comment: @YungLinMa `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype;`